# Calling multiple linux processes in Python and collecting output

Tags: python, process, output, external

From a Python script, I need to call a PL->EN translation service. The translation requires 3 steps: tokenization, translation, detoknization

From Linux, I can achieve this using 3 processes by the following commands executed in mentioned order:

```
/home/nlp/opt/moses/scripts/tokenizer/tokenizer.perl -l pl < path_to_input.txt > path_to_output.tok.txt

/home/nlp/opt/moses/bin/moses -f /home/nlp/Downloads/TED/tuning/moses.tuned.ini.1 -drop-unknown -input-file path_to_output.tok.txt -th 8 > path_to_output.trans.txt

/home/nlp/opt/moses/scripts/tokenizer/detokenizer.perl -l en < path_to_output.trans.txt > path_to_output.final.txt
```

which translates the file `path_to_input.txt` and outputs to `path_to_output.final.txt`

I have made the following script for combining the 3 processes:

```
import shlex
import subprocess
from subprocess import STDOUT,PIPE
import os
import socket

class Translator:
    @staticmethod
    def pl_to_en(input_file, output_file):
        # Tokenize
        print("Tokenization started")
        with open("tokenized.txt", "w+") as tokenizer_output:
            with open(input_file) as tokenizer_input:
                cmd = "/home/nlp/opt/moses/scripts/tokenizer/tokenizer.perl -    l pl"
                args = shlex.split(cmd)
                p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=tokenizer_input, stdout=tokenizer_output)
                p.wait()
                print("Tokenization finished")

        #Translate
        print("Translation started")
        with open("translated.txt", "w+") as translator_output:
            cmd = "/home/nlp/opt/moses/bin/moses -f /home/nlp/Downloads/TED/tuning/moses.tuned.ini.1 -drop-unknown -input-file tokenized.txt -th 8"
            args = shlex.split(cmd)
            p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=translator_output)
            p.wait()
            print("Translation finished")

        # Detokenize
        print("Detokenization started")
        with open("translated.txt") as detokenizer_input:
            with open("detokenized.txt", "w+") as detokenizer_output:
                cmd = "/home/nlp/opt/moses/scripts/tokenizer/detokenizer.perl -l en"
                args = shlex.split(cmd)
                p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=detokenizer_input, stdout=detokenizer_output)
                p.wait()
                print("Detokenization finished")

translator = Translator()
translator.pl_to_en("some_input_file.txt", "some_output_file.txt")
```

But only the tokenization part works.
The translator just outputs an empty file `translated.txt`. When looking at the output in the terminal, it looks like the translator loads the file tokenized.txt correctly, and does a translation. The problem is just how I collect the output from that process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like the following - sending the output of the translator process to the pipe, and making the input of the detokenizer the pipe instead of using the files.

```
import shlex
import subprocess
from subprocess import STDOUT,PIPE
import os
import socket

class Translator:
    @staticmethod
    def pl_to_en(input_file, output_file):
        # Tokenize
        print("Tokenization started")
        with open("tokenized.txt", "w+") as tokenizer_output:
            with open(input_file) as tokenizer_input:
                cmd = "/home/nlp/opt/moses/scripts/tokenizer/tokenizer.perl -    l pl"
                args = shlex.split(cmd)
                p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=tokenizer_input, stdout=tokenizer_output)
                p.wait()
                print("Tokenization finished")

        #Translate
        print("Translation started")
        cmd = "/home/nlp/opt/moses/bin/moses -f /home/nlp/Downloads/TED/tuning/moses.tuned.ini.1 -drop-unknown -input-file tokenized.txt -th 8"
        args = shlex.split(cmd)
        translate_p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        translate_p.wait()
        print("Translation finished")
    # Detokenize
        print("Detokenization started")
        with open("detokenized.txt", "w+") as detokenizer_output:
            cmd = "/home/nlp/opt/moses/scripts/tokenizer/detokenizer.perl -l en"
            args = shlex.split(cmd)
            detokenizer_p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=translate_p.stdout, stdout=detokenizer_output)
            detokenizer_p.wait()
            print("Detokenization finished")

translator = Translator()
translator.pl_to_en("some_input_file.txt", "some_output_file.txt")
```

Comment: With this solution, everything works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: My pleasure.  Cheers!